# What's the difference between economies of scale and increasing returns to scale?

Tags: production-function, firm

Can anyone tell me the difference between economies of scale and increasing returns to scale. It seems to me that observationally they would be equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

**Economies of scale** are normally understood to refer to a situation in which, as output is increased, the cost *per unit* of producing that output falls (see [here](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/e/economiesofscale.asp) and [here](https://stats.oecd.org/glossary/detail.asp?ID=3203)).

**Increasing returns to scale** are normally understood to refer to a situation in which, as all inputs are increased k-fold, output increases more than k-fold (see [here](https://xplaind.com/196977/returns-to-scale) and [here](https://stats.oecd.org/glossary/detail.asp?ID=2350)).  This is equivalent to saying that a k-fold increase in output can be achieved by increasing all inputs less than k-fold.  The difference from economies of scale is that returns to scale are about the relation between inputs and output and nothing is implied about costs.

If a firm producing a good X is a price-taker in the markets for all the inputs it uses to produce X, and if those markets do not offer any form of discount for bulk purchases, then a k-fold increase in input quantities will imply a k-fold increase in cost, and vice versa.  In those circumstances, the firm will benefit from economies of scale if and only if it enjoys increasing returns to scale.